# How can I set a date to past in Postman and add 1 day to it

Tags: javascript, automation, postman

I am trying to add a day to a date variable set in environment variables but unable to do so. Tried following until now:

Set Environment variables as:

```
start_date = 2018-11-14
```

adding 1 to the environment variable appends 1 to it as its considered as a string probably

```
environment.start_date = environment.start_date + 1
```

makes it `2018-11-141`

Explored JS moment library but it seems to work with the current date unless I failed to understand its usage

Will appreciate some help for this noviice question..

Answer (score 1):

```
let moment= require('moment')

a= moment("2018-11-14","YYYY-MM-DD").subtract("day",1).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

use moment ,

Answer (score 0):

const moment = require('moment');

var beforeToday = moment().subtract(10, 'day');
pm.globals.set("beforeToday", beforeToday.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

var afterToday = moment().add(1,'day');
pm.globals.set("afterToday", afterToday.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).